# How to disassociate file types on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-association

My .bin files were normal, then I thought that I could use them in Windows Media Player. So now they open with Windows Media Player but I want to disassociate the .bin file type. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

There is a 3rd party utility to disassociate file types on Windows 7 and Vista.

- Download [unassoc.zip](http://www.winhelponline.com/downloadattachment.php?aId=c060d239de9af876a20a6374973bb60a&articleId=231)
- Extract the contents to a folder and run the file unassoc.exe
- Select the file type (.bin) from the list
- Click "Remove file association (User)"

[image]

Here is the [resource page](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/231/1/An-Utility-to-Unassociate-File-Types-in-Windows-7-and-Vista.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Press Win+R
2. Type `cmd` and press enter
3. In the command prompt type "assoc .bin= " (without quotes), be sure to press space after typing "=" and then press enter.

Comment: @pico, how would you use that command to associate something with a file extension? would you set a path to the program?

Comment: See [assoc](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/assoc.mspx?mfr=true) and also [Ftype](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftype.mspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a real world example. Say I wanted to set an association for .mp3 to a specific audio program.

Comment: There is one on the Ftype page I linked above, just replace the references to perl with others appropriate to the situation, e.g. Moab.mp3 instead of PerlScript and your favorite player instead of perl.exe. The MP3 file type hasn't a general name, but rather one that is application specific e.g. VLC.mp3

Comment: I have no scripting or programming education, if I cannot see a real world example this advice does me no good, thanks for trying.